# Adding tables to the WordPress Editor

Tags: functions, editor, visual-editor

I tried this fix:
http://www.paulund.co.uk/display-full-tinymce-editor-in-wordpress

But I see no change in my editor. So how do I enable tables in the wordpress editor.

MY function is:

```
function tinyMCETables($args)
{
 $args['theme_advanced_blockformats'] = 'p,address,pre,code,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6';
 $args['wordpress_adv_hidden'] = false;
 return $args;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'tinyMCETables' );
```

And yes, I know about the tincMCE Advanced plugin but I want to build the feature into my theme.  Is there another way to enable tables?

Comment: I don't see your tinyMCETables function actually adding anything to do with tables.

Answer (score 1):

**updated with more explanation**

If you want to build this into your theme - [this tutorial](http://www.allchorn.com/2008/09/19/how-to-implement-table-editing-in-wordpress/) for adding some code to functions.php will work.  Keep in mind you *will* have to download TinyMCE and add files to /wp-includes for this to work.

That's because "table management" is a plugin for TinyMCE and doesn't ship with Wordpress.  For that reason, I would highly recommend just using a plugin.

**Relevant Links**

- [functions.php tutorial](http://www.allchorn.com/2008/09/19/how-to-implement-table-editing-in-wordpress/)
- [advanced plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/)
- [light-weight plugin](http://10up.com/plugins/wordpress-mce-table-buttons/)